# Resource Caching: Candidate for Synchronous Execution in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, asynchronous, synchronous

Whenever someone asks "can I do this synchronously?" The inevitable answer is "you shouldn't."  I'm faced with a problem that seems like a candidate for breaking this pat answer: resource caching.

I'm working on a Twitter client that uses application-only authentication.  You have to request an access token that lasts for a certain length of time.  This token must be used on any subsequent requests.

At some point, the token will expire, and API call with fail with the appropriate error message, at which point I'll know I need to request another token, and then re-issue the API request.

What I am trying to avoid is this:

```
var _accessToken;

function getAccessToken(cb){
    if(_accessToken) return cb();
    // construct options object....
    https.request(options, function(res){
        // extract access token from res
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        cb();
    }).end();
}

function get(path, cb){
    this.getAccessToken(function(){
        // construct options object using _accessToken
        https.request(options, function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data.errors[0].code===89){
                // delete expired access token
                delete _accessToken;
                // recursively call self; will get
                // new access token
                return get(path, cb);
            }
            // access token valid, invoke cb with response
            cb(data);
        });
    });
}
```

To me that just sounds like madness.  I'll have to wrap EVERY API access call within a callback and recursively call itself when it's realized that the access token has expired.  What I would rather do is this:

```
var _accessToken;

function getAccessTokenSync(){
    if(_accessToken) return _accessToken;
    // make *synchronous* call to https.request, set
    // _accessToken, then return it
}

function get(path, cb){
    // construct options object using getAccessTokenSync()
    https.request(options, function(data){
        if(data.errors[0].code===89) {
            delete _accessToken;
            return get(path, cb);
        }
        cb(data);
    }
}
```

Am I wrong in thinking that this is a legitimate reason to make something synchronous?  Essentially, the HTTP request will happen only rarely, and normally, a cached value will simply be returned.

I've run into the same problem with pretty much anything that involves some kind of token or handle that can be cached.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?  Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be synchronous? What about:

```
function getAccessTokenSync(_callback){
    if(_accessToken) return _callback();

    // make regular call to https.request
    https.request(options, function(res){
        // extract access token from res
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        _callback();
    }).end();
}
```

Comment: Hi, MWay, it doesn't _have_ to be synchronous, but your suggestion results in the same problem as my "this is what I'm trying to avoid" example.  You make a good point, though: I left out a line in my "what I'm trying to avoid" example, which I'll update now.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I wrong in thinking that this is a legitimate reason to make something synchronous?

Yes, if this "something" takes more than 10 milliseconds to work.

`getAccessToken` function can make HTTP request which can take anywhere from 100ms to 30s to complete, so blocking the loop for such a long time is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Yes, alex, but what about a method (such as the one I'm asking about) only invokes an HTTP request every 100 calls, or every 1000, or every 10000?  Or every hour?  Or 24 hours?  Surely there's a point at which the expense of dealing with callbacks is negated by the infrequency of a 100ms block.

Comment: So once per every 1000 requests your server will freeze, and somebody will spend a great deal of time investigating why... Huh. No, there is no such point.

Comment: Who said anything about the _server freezing_?  I'm _certainly_ not suggesting a blocking approach.  If I were to take a synchronous approach, I'm certainly not enough of a n00b to block the whole server.  Just the specific request.  I would definitely use some "await" library to create make the synchronous call nonblocking.

Comment: Oh, in that case generators would help, look at https://github.com/visionmedia/co module.

Answer (score 0):

I think, writing functions that return value is what we used to do in most other languages and   it is a mental block for node programming.

Think this way. Rather than returning a value of your function, think what you plan to do with the "return value".

Whatever it is, pass it to the function and the function will invoke it with the right value at the right time.

HTH.

Comment: Yes and no, palanik.  Certainly, I come from the procedural world, but I've been doing JavaScript and Node for long enough that I don't feel I'm suffering from that mental block anymore.  However, _any_ paradigm can break down, including asynchronous programming.  "Callback hell" is a real thing, and people are finding ways to deal with it.  In the next version of JavaScript, we will have access to _generators_, which will largely solve this problem, but for now, we're stuck with libraries that emulate generators.